# sphinxQL fetching random?

Tags: sphinx, sphinxql

In SphinxQL, how do I get random records from index?

```
SELECT fname FROM indexname WHERE Age>=21 and Age<=47 random 0,4 \G;
```

Getting following error:

```
sphinxql: syntax error, unexpected CONST_INT, expecting BETWEEN (or 8 other tokens) near '0,4
```

Any other way to getting random record from SphinxQl?

Answer (score 3):

All you need is

```
... ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4
```

Comment: thanks its works , how we can add more than one order by like ,      order by rank , age  desc limit 4