# Get 50 random rows from Sphinx query

Tags: random, sphinx

I have a PHP website using Sphinx by **sphinxClient lib**.

My Sphinx query has some filters and a limit of 2500 rows.  From the 2500 rows (could be less), I want to fetch just 50 random rows.

Is there a way to do it using only Sphinx?

Edit: The original query already sorted by the popularity of the rows, the main idea is to get 50 random products from the 2500 most popular. Because of that I can't sort by random

Answer (score 0):

See `SPH_SORT_EXTENDED`. There is a `@random` sort order

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#sorting-modes

Comment: My original query already sorted by the popularity of the rows, the main idea is to get 50 random products from the 2500 most popular

Comment: Hmm, well that is more tricky. There is a setOuterSelect. Its undocumented, but can find it in sphinxapi.php.  Might be a good opportunity to convert to SphinxQL, where its available as a subselect which is more intutive.

Comment: I'm using an older version of sphinx, so I don't gave the setOuterSelect. Also, A lot of places in my system relied on the sphinx so I can't use the SphinxQL. There is another way to implement it?

Comment: I guess that means you SOL then.

Answer (score 0):

What's the issue with using order by RAND() limit 50

Check this link for similar result.
[sphinxQL fetching random?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15434291/sphinxql-fetching-random)

Comment: My original query already sorted by the popularity of the rows, the main idea is to get 50 random products from the 2500 most popular