# Is there a way to randomize search results (record ids) with Sphinx?

Tags: random, sphinx

I have a complex SphinxQL query which, at the end, orders results by a specific field, `Preferred`, so that all records with that indexed value of Preferred=1 come before all records w Preferred=0. I also order by weight() so basically I end up with:

`Select * from idx_X where MATCH('various parameters') ORDER by Preferred DESC,Weight() Desc`

The problem is that, though Preferred records come first I end up with records sorted by ID which puts results from one field, Vendor, in blocks so for instance I get:

`Beta Shipping
Beta Shipping
Beta Shipping
Acme Widgets
Acme Widgets
Acme Widgets
Acme Widgets
Acme Widgets`

Which doesn't serve my purposes in this case well (often one 'Vendor' will have 1000 results)

So I'm looking to essentially do:

`ORDER BY Preferred DESC,weight() DESC,ID RANDOM`

So that after getting to Preferred Vendors whose weight is (e.g.) `100`, I will get random Vendors vs blocks of them.

**Update**: Though I did find what appears to be a possible answer in another [Stackoveflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22011194/get-50-random-rows-from-sphinx-query)

The issue is it seems to require the `SPH_SORT_EXTENDED` and I am forced to use `SPH_RANK_PROXIMITY` (ranker=proximity) and I am unclear if I can combine ranking and sorting.

Update 2: If I remove my existing two-level Order and just do `Order by Rand()` it indeed returns random IDs. However I cannot add `Rand()` after `Order by Preferred DESC,Weight() DESC` or I get the following error:

`1064 - sphinxql: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting $end near '()`

Comment: Sort Mode, is completely seperate to Ranking mode, and seperate to Match Mode too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly yes, `RAND()` only works as a single sort order expression, but it DOES work as a select function....

```
Select *, RAND() AS r from idx_X where MATCH('various parameters') 
 ORDER by Preferred DESC,Weight() Desc, r DESC
```

Or if want a more consistent ordering, but still mixed, can for example use `CRC32()` function on a string atribute

```
Select *, CRC32(title) AS r from idx_X where MATCH('various parameters') 
 ORDER by Preferred DESC,Weight() Desc, r DESC
```

Can also just limit results to a few per vendor (vendor will need to be an attribute)

```
Select * from idx_X where MATCH('various parameters') 
 GROUP 3 BY vendor_id ORDER by Preferred DESC,Weight() Desc
```

*Group by N* is a little known by very useful sphinx feature.

Comment: Thanks the first one throws this error though `> 1064 - sphinxql: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting FROM or ',' near '() AS r`

Comment: the CRC32 returns `sort-by attribute 'r' not found`

Comment: Interesting it was ok with `as RANDOMIZER` and `Order by RANDOMIZER Desc` it just did not like the single letter.

Comment: CRC32(title) worked great in fact. I maintained Preferred and Weight() but now have a nice randomization. Thanks!

Comment: Cool. Hash functions are generally very good, for 'mixing' results up. But keeping things consistent between repeat calls. Very useful for search results, and wont vary each time load, and also still works when paging through results :)

Comment: As an anecdote this was especially helpful as prior to this I had to add another randomize during the PHP so that each vendor had a chance to be 'first' in any given 'Preferred' sort and do so on a user session by user session basis (so each one had a chance to be 'first' in front of any given user). Now I can get rid of that clumsy approach and make sure they each have the chance to show up early on in any given search.

Comment: In checking this further I run into a weird issue; if I run the same sphinx query with the CRC32(title) multiple times in a row, I get the exact same order each time. Do I need to somehow 'reset' as this is the opposite of random?

Comment: Umm, thats the point! using CRC32 IS consistent, it will give same results each time, its NOT random. Its like shuffling deck of cards with a consistent agorithm. May be mixed, but always the same. If you want **changing** results using use `RAND()`

Comment: Hmm ok that is interesting. It means that in my case each individual search will always give the same 'random' sort but that all my different searches will, while consistently given consistent results, provide different Preferred Vendors first? In other words I have the advantage of having consistent results if a user searches twice AND I can also put different Preferred Vendors for different searches?

Comment: So in continued checking I get the same Preferred Vendor first in any search I do. I had thought it might make it the same one in any given specific search but for each search a different sort of preferred vendors in each weight sort. I tried doing RAND() as R but I get `> 1064 - sphinxql: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting FROM or ',' near '() as R`. So right now unless I miunderstand what is happening all I've done is randomly make a single preferred vendor always first vs doing it by alpha or something else.

Comment: `Group By` would be more useful here if it didn't limit the total # of records per vendor but limited the # of sequential ones. In any event sort of stuck now; I have no good way of randomly putting vendors in each block of weighted results.

Comment: So summary of issue and my possible solution; `RAND() ` does not work even as select. `CRC32(Title)` doesn't give each Vendor an equal chance at being first but does randomize results in each `Weight()`. `CRC32(Vendor)` makes the same vendor's jobs go first in every search. My thought is perhaps I could combine the two strings e.g. `CRC32(Vendor,Title)` but that syntax doesn't work neither does my next try `CRC32(Concat(Vendor,Title))`. The idea is to introduce randomization between searches in terms of which vendors go first and not having blocks of vendors.

Comment: Do have a UniqueSerial UDF http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=10553 that can do it.

Comment: I have to admit that thread sort of lost me. Are you asking if each Vendor has a unique VendorID? If so than yes. Do you mind elaborating on how I can then use that VendorID to randomize or CRC32 randomize on the VendorID so each vendor has an equal chance of showing up in results vs being weighted towards the one with the most records and/or always the same vendor?

Comment: I've been looking at your comments in http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=10546. Seems to me it puts me back where I started anyway, the vendorsort happening before the order, the order being critical since it puts Featured Vendors first and then inside that order puts weighted/relevance. It seems to me a feature request to allow e.g. Rand(Title) in order would make sense e.g. `Order by Weight(),Rand)(Vendor`.

Comment: I'm moving this to another question as I think it desrves one so thank you!